# c# convert image to byte array

Tags: c#, byte, screenshot

i was loooking for a faster solution to convert image to byte array using the regular method:

```
   public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
 {
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
  return  ms.ToArray();
 }
```

so i searched and found this one

```
public static byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
    {

        BitmapData bmpdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        int numbytes = bmpdata.Stride * bitmap.Height;

        numbytes = Math.Abs(numbytes);

        byte[] bytedata = new byte[numbytes];
        IntPtr ptr = bmpdata.Scan0;

        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytedata, 0, numbytes);

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpdata);

        return bytedata;

    }
```

this is my call:

```
 `   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       Bitmap curr = GetDesktopImage();

        byte[] buff = BitmapToByteArray(curr);


        }
```

than i got an expcetion `arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow`  and i discoverd that `numbofbytes` was negative so it couldn't make the array so i used `Math.Abs()` but than i got another error on that line `Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytedata, 0, numbytes);` and the error **: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**  why is it happening? 
`GetDesktopImage()` is a method i have that uses the gdi to take screenshots according to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3024/Capturing-the-Screen-Image-in-C) and the method is actully (i tried to display on picturebox) but im facing weird errors when trying to convert to bytes..

this is GetDesktopImage()

```
 public static Bitmap GetDesktopImage()
    {
        //In size variable we shall keep the size of the screen.
        SIZE size;

        //Variable to keep the handle to bitmap.
        IntPtr hBitmap;

        IntPtr hDC = PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetDC(PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetDesktopWindow());

        IntPtr hMemDC = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

        size.cx = PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetSystemMetrics(PlatformInvokeUSER32.SM_CXSCREEN);

        size.cy = PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetSystemMetrics(PlatformInvokeUSER32.SM_CYSCREEN);

        hBitmap = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, size.cx, size.cy);

        if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

            IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr)PlatformInvokeGDI32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

            PlatformInvokeGDI32.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, size.cx, size.cy, hDC, 0, 0, PlatformInvokeGDI32.SRCCOPY);

            PlatformInvokeGDI32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);

            PlatformInvokeGDI32.DeleteDC(hMemDC);

            PlatformInvokeUSER32.ReleaseDC(PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);

            Bitmap bmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

            PlatformInvokeGDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

            GC.Collect();

            return bmp;
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be faster than your first working method, are you trying to create video of the desktop using `GetDesktopImage()`? Also the reason `numbytes` is negative is likely because `bmpdata.Stride * bitmap.Height` is larger than a `int` can hold.

Comment: Side note: There is almost no chance that handling uncompressed image leads to overall better performance/memory usage. Screenshots are generally very compressible, so you may be forcing yourself to deal with 10-50x more memory than needed for compressed image.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i dont think that's the reason because when i try to print the stride  it's aleardy negative :( and no i dont want to make a video

Answer (score 0):

For the negative stride, the [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The stride is the width of a single row of pixels (a scan line), rounded up to a four-byte boundary. If the stride is positive, the bitmap is top-down. If the stride is negative, the bitmap is bottom-up.

Your bitmap is bottom-up. Have a look at this nice explanation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx

To copy the bytes, you need to calculate the starting address like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17116072/200443.

If you want to reverse the bytes order, you need to copy one line at a time.